# Java UnsupportedOperationException with Collection objects

Tags: java, collections

I have an error using Java Collections in JDK 1.7 :
I got this Exception in this line:  **proposalStatuses.addAll(getAllSubmittedStatuses())**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
```

trying to add a collection to a list

```
/**
     * Gets the all submitted statuses.
     *
     * @return the all submitted statuses
     */
    private Collection<ProposalStatus> getAllSubmittedStatuses() {

        return Arrays.asList(
                  ProposalStatus.SAVED_TO_IOS
                , ProposalStatus.SENDED_TO_IOS_IN_PROGRESS
                );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the all received statuses.
     *
     * @return the all received statuses
     */
    private Collection<ProposalStatus> getAllReceivedStatuses() {

        Collection<ProposalStatus> proposalStatuses =

                Arrays.asList(
                  ProposalStatus.RECEIVED_BY_IOS
                , ProposalStatus.SUBMITTED_TO_IOS
                , ProposalStatus.RECEIVED_IOS
                );

        proposalStatuses.addAll(getAllSubmittedStatuses());

        return proposalStatuses;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [javadoc of `Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a **fixed-size list** backed by the specified array

In short: you cannot `.add*()` or `.remove*()` from such a List! You'll have to use another modifiable List implementation (`ArrayList` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

To explain a bit more practically, I am using your code:

```
private Collection<ProposalStatus> getAllSubmittedStatuses() {

    // This returns a list that cannot be modified, fixed size
    return Arrays.asList(
              ProposalStatus.SAVED_TO_IOS
            , ProposalStatus.SENDED_TO_IOS_IN_PROGRESS
            );
}

/**
 * Gets the all received statuses.
 *
 * @return the all received statuses
 */
private Collection<ProposalStatus> getAllReceivedStatuses() {

    // proposalStatuses will be a fixed-size list so no changing
    Collection<ProposalStatus> proposalStatuses =

            Arrays.asList(
              ProposalStatus.RECEIVED_BY_IOS
            , ProposalStatus.SUBMITTED_TO_IOS
            , ProposalStatus.RECEIVED_IOS
            );

    // This will not be possible, also you cannot remove anything.
    proposalStatuses.addAll(getAllSubmittedStatuses());

    return proposalStatuses;
}
```

For your purpose, I would do the the following:

```
return new ArrayList<ProposalStatus>(Arrays.asList(ProposalStatus.SAVED_TO_IOS,ProposalStatus.SENDED_TO_IOS_IN_PROGRESS)
```

This should help you get the Collection objects.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` returns an immutable list, that you cannot modify.

More specifically, add(), addAll() and remove() methods are not implemented.